# Error when extend on_change method in invoice_line

Tags: python, odoo

I try to extend the method product_id_change from the model account.invoice.line :

class account_invoice_line(models.Model):

_inherit = 'account.invoice.line'

```
  @api.multi

  def product_id_change(self, product, uom_id, qty=0, name='', type_x='out_invoice',

                                      partner_id=False, fposition_id=False, price_unit=False, currency_id=False,

                                      company_id=None):

        res = super(account_invoice_line, self).product_id_change(self,product, uom_id, qty, name, type_x, partner_id,                                                                                                         fposition_id, price_unit, currency_id, company_id)

        return res.
```

But i'have this error when i call product_id_change with super : TypeError: product_id_change() takes at most 11 arguments (12 given) .

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Looks like you're missing some code, half a line is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove self from super method calling line.

```
res = super(account_invoice_line, self).product_id_change(product, uom_id, qty=0, name='', type_x='out_invoice',partner_id=False, fposition_id=False, price_unit=False, currency_id=False,
company_id=None)
```

No need pass self explicitly to any method, invoking object set automatically in this parameter.